# Google Drive Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to get the cell color to change if for instance
A1-A2 is > 0 THEN A3 is Green.

I can't seem to get this to work at all.
Any help here would be great!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a Custom CF format rule to A3:

[image: Custom CF format rule]